# How can i access custom decorator from the module in the django app view

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, python-3.6, python-module

This is my project directory.

[image: Directory Structure]

API is an app in this structure whereas mappingdecorator is a python package that I created. It has a file mappingdecorator which has a decorator. I want to make this decorator available in the API app.

Below is the code I wrote to access it in the API file.

```
from proj.proj.mappingdecorator.mappingdecorator import mapping_the_fields


@api_view(['GET'])
@mapping_the_fields
def user_view(request, id=None):
 #code
```

I am purposely omitting the code inside mappingdecorator file and my api_view since I tested both of them in the same file and they were working but separation made a mess and threw an exception on execution.

This is the runtime error i am getting:

```
  from proj.proj.mappingdecorator.mappingdecorator import mapping_the_fields
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'proj.proj'
```

Comment: Are you sure you got your import path right? Shouldn't it be ```from proj.mappingdecorator.mappingdecorator import mapping_the_fields```?

Comment: yes when i import like this proj.mappingdecorator.mappingdecorator import mapping_the_fields i get error even before runtime time.